# Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Credentials'

Tags: swift

I have a function where I'm trying to return a valid Credentials object:

```
func getCredentials() -> Credentials {
    credentialsManager.credentials { error, credentials in
        guard error == nil, let credentials = credentials else {
            return presentLoginPage()
        }
        return credentials
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error `Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Credentials'` on the credentialsManager.credentials line.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. What is the return type of `presentLoginPage()`? What is the function signature of `credentialsManager.credentials`

Comment: From the looks of it, `credentialsManager.credentials` is an async function with a completion handler. You can't return a value synchronously from an async method.

Comment: That message can occur if presentLoginPage() is not returning Credentials. () means presentLoginPage() is returning nothing.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I think this was closed prematurely. One of the returns likely does not match the return type straight out rather than being a timing issue.

Comment: @Marcy do you understand how async functions work in Swift? The function signature of a sync and async function are completely different. So trying to return synchronously from an async function will result in a compiler error rather than a runtime timing issue.